# Repeating a method call on each direcotry with timer elasped in C#

Tags: c#, timer, filesystems, zip, filesystemwatcher

Overview:

I've created two `FileSystemWatcher` to detect sub-folders and its files creation. I also use a `Timer` to the second watcher(file watcher), which restart the timer for every file created to any of each folder before calling a zip method dynamically.

I try to make this process to every folder, but it zips all folder at once regardless if there is a file moving into those folders.

Below is part of my code to simulate the timer and zip process... I might have a problem moving the zip file to root folder when calling the zip method.

The Timer inside the file Watcher

```
namespace ZipperAndWatcher
{
    public class Archive
    {
        public void CreateZip(string path)
        {    
          // zip method code
        }

    }

    public class FileWatcher
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher _fsw;
        private Archive _zip;
        private string _path;
        private Timer _timer;

        public FileWatcher()
        {
            _fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
            _zip = new Archive();

            _path = @"D:\Documents\output";
            _timer = new Timer();
        }

        public void StartWatching()
        {
            var rootWatcher = _fsw;
            rootWatcher.Path = _path;
            rootWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnRootFolderCreated);
            rootWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            rootWatcher.Filter = "*.*";
        }

        private void OnRootFolderCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string watchedPath = e.FullPath; // watched path

            // create another watcher for file creation and send event to timer
            FileSystemWatcher subFolderWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            subFolderWatcher.Path = watchedPath + @"\";

            // Timer setting
            var aTimer = _timer;
            aTimer.Interval = 20000;

            // Lambda == args => expression
            // send event to subFolderWatcher
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((subfolderSender, evt) => OnTimedEvent(subfolderSender, evt, subFolderWatcher));
            aTimer.AutoReset = false;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            // sub-folder sends event to timer (and wait timer to notify subfolder)
            subFolderWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((s, evt) => subFolderWatcher_Created(s, evt, aTimer));
            subFolderWatcher.Filter = "*.*";
            subFolderWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs evt, FileSystemWatcher subFolderWatcher)
        {
            subFolderWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            // Explicit Casting
            Timer timer = sender as Timer;
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();

            // Once time elapsed, zip the folder here?
            Console.WriteLine($"time up. zip process at {evt.SignalTime}");               
            Archive zip = _zip;
            zip.CreateZip(subFolderWatcher.Path.Substring(0, subFolderWatcher.Path.LastIndexOf(@"\")));

            subFolderWatcher.Dispose();
        }

        private void subFolderWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs evt, Timer aTimer)
        {
            // if new file created, stop the timer
            //  then restart the timer
            aTimer.AutoReset = false;
            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"restart the timer as {evt.Name} created on {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set up the file system watchers and their timers? I wonder how the event handlers get their extra parameters.

Comment: I set the 2nd watcher and timer inside the OnCreated event handler of the root folder, extended with the code above, which the 2nd watcher sends an event to the timer and also the timer sends an event to the 2nd watcher to interact each other to some extent. I'm not sure how to proceed the zip process to each folder individually.

Comment: Could you please add this code to the question?

Comment: @KlausGütter my code might be long and ugly, but you can find it [here](https://rextester.com/MDG55103). My apology.

Comment: Frankly, I don't get your probem. Is it that your CreateZip method always zips all subdirectories and not only the one where a new file has been added? If you do not want this, just pass the path to the correct directory to the method and remove the foreach loop on the subdirectories from CreateZip.

Comment: @KlausGütter my problem is the zip method always zip all subdirectories at the same time, but what I want is to only zip the specific subdirectories, which has no more files being added after the time elapsed while other subdirectories might still have files adding in, and it is not ready to be zipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in your last comment: "what I want is to only zip the specific subdirectories, which has no more files being added after the time elapsed while other subdirectories might still have files adding in, and it is not ready to be zipped"

So in your timer handler (OnTimedEvent), you need to pass the path to the directory that is ready for zipping to CreateZip, not the parent directory, i.e. change

```
zip.CreateZip(subFolderWatcher.Path.Substring(0, subFolderWatcher.Path.LastIndexOf(@"\")));
```

to

```
zip.CreateZip(subFolderWatcher.Path);
```

Then in your CreateZip method just zip the directory that is passed as parameter, not all subdirectories as you do now.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but what If I want each subdirectory zip itself at different time elapsed, Wonder should I remove the `foreach` in the zip method?

Comment: If I understood your code correctly, you have a timer per subdirectory, so these would already operate independently.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what the timer does, but I want each subdirectory should zip itself once (1)time elapsed and (2)no more files being added in that subdirectory. I still cannot make this works.

Comment: Don't you already restart the timer whenever a new file arrives? This should handle (1) and (2).